# How to remove a whole line depend by the keyword?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to import multiple data file in React because the data sets might be so large, so I need to spilt a big file to many files

I only know how to import one data file in React, I know how to import 2 kind of data, but I don't know how to import somethings like

myText1 and myText2 and combine them together and read it

```
   componentDidMount() {
        const promiseForText = axios.get(`${myText}`)
        const promiseForAccount = axios.get('./account.json')
        Promise.all([promiseForText, promiseForAccount]).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                data: response[0].data,
                account: response[1].data,
            })
        })
    }
```

I hope I can get the data from  file1 file2.... fileN

and combine all of it and read it in my component.

Comment: I don't see any relation between description and title. I don't see any "file" in your code, only axios request. I don't know what you mean by "import", which usually involve `<input type='file' />`. I don't understand what you're really asking. Consider rewrite your description.

Comment: I just didn't show you the picture ... it ca be any file at another folder..

Comment: Try explain the word "import" with code. I don't get what you mean by using the word.

Comment: by any chance, did you include that code example trying to show us how you "import" 2 kind of data? If so, then...man you got a strange understanding of that word.

Comment: What you did in that code example, normally we don't call that "import 2 data files", we call that "send ajax requests for 2 chunk of data, one JSON, one plain text". No "import", no "file" involve.

Answer (score 0):

```
    componentDidMount() {
        const promiseForMyText1 = axios.get('./myText1.txt')
        const promiseForMyText2 = axios.get('./myText2.txt')
        const promiseForMyText3 = axios.get('./myText3.txt')
        const promiseForText = Promise.all([
            promiseForMyText1, promiseForMyText2, promiseForMyText3
        ]).then(resList => {
            return resList.reduce((acc, res) => acc + res.data, '')
        })

        const promiseForAccount = axios.get('./account.json')
        Promise.all([promiseForText, promiseForAccount]).then(([myText, resForAccount]) => {
            this.setState({
                data: myText,
                account: resForAccount.data,
            })
        })
    }
```